# My linux server uses less space than ACTUALLY available

Tags: disk-usage, disk

I use linux only to run my TF2 server and host some private shit. Today I tried to upload 80gb file but failed several times. I found out the issue. I have 250gb SSD but my linux for whatever reason uses only 111Gb. How to fix this?[image]

Comment: You'd probably want to [extend your logical volume](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/).

Comment: Because your sda3 partition contains an lvm which only uses half of the SSD. The other half of the SSD partition is not mounted, and may not even have a valid file system in it.

Comment: `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/sda3/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` and then depending on your filesystem `resize2fs` should work. Note that shrinking can not be done as easily as extending...

Comment: @rudib unfortunately this doesnt work

root@serwer:~# lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/sda3/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Volume group "sda3" not found
  Cannot process volume group sda3

Comment: I probably guessed the name wrong. Please run `lvdisplay` and update your question with the output. When posting outputs, please use text and format it as code whenever possible.

Comment: @rudib I got it working by the time you replied, you got the path wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[image]Ok, I managed to do it like this guide said.
https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

I did:
lvdisplay
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

Comment: you should copy the texts from the terminal and paste them here instead of taking a screenshot